# How to Count rows If Current Column `Id` is Matching from Another Table in Codeignitor PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing a School erp in Codeignitor. I'm facing an issue while counting the no of rows. Here Let me explain.

This is my Class Table.

[image]

Here, this is the student Table.

[image]

and this is my view
[image]




So, I want to count student from table student and print the number in box below the class name.
as you can see that the `id`fro table class is matching from the clumne `class_id` in Table Student.

Here is my Model Code:-

```
 //get class list in box 
     function getClassList() {
        $query = $this->db->select('*')->get('classes');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

My Controller:-

```
function classlist() {

    if (!$this->rbac->hasPrivilege('student', 'can_view')) {
        access_denied();
    }
    $this->session->set_userdata('top_menu', 'Student Information');
    $this->session->set_userdata('sub_menu', 'student/search');
    $data['title'] = 'Student Search';
    $clist = $this->student_model->getClassList();
    $data['clist'] = $clist;
        $this->load->view('layout/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('student/studentSearch', $data);
        $this->load->view('layout/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

and here My view page:-

```
            <?php foreach ($clist as $key  ) {
                ?>


                <div class="info-box">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>student/stdlists/<?php echo $key['id']; ?>">
                        <span class="info-box-icon bg-green"><i class="fa fa-child"></i></span>
                        <div class="info-box-content">
                            <span class="info-box-text"><?php echo $key['class']; ?></span>

                            <span class="info-box-number">**I want to Print The Total Count here**</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>     

        <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need left join and group by in function getClassList.

Final query shoud be something like this:

```
select count(t.id) as students_in_class, s.*
from class s
left join student t on s.id = t.class_id
group by t.class_id
```

but you using ORM and I not familiar with it....